# Freeform Width affects the loaded view

Tags: ios, xib

I have defined a .xib file with two buttons which is of freeform style. When I load this view into another view either there is space left at the right for phones like iphone 7 plus and in phones like iphone 5s only half the button is visible.

**This is my .xib file.**
[image: This is my .xib file.]

**This is the image after loading in iphone5s**

[image: This is the image after loading in iphone5s]

**This is the image after loading in iphone 7plus**

[image: This is the image after loading in iphone 7plus]

Comment: Did you set up constraints for the views?

Comment: its your constarints problem, check once in preview

Comment: Yeah I have set margin constarints left,right,top,bottom

Comment: The problem is  based on the width of the freeform the view and it's content are changing the width. That's why in iphone 7plus there is space left at the right while in iphone 5s there is no space.

Comment: no , absolutely not, set your constarint in min device it automatically adjust to all devices

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how do I set constraint in min device? Can you explain? I am a newbie?

Comment: I have set constraint as far as i know

Comment: @Prabu - what ever you did is correct and fine, just move the same work from iphone7s to iphone min device and check once in preview once you get the right anser

Comment: Even in iphon7 plus I don't get the epxected output @Anbu.Karthik. There is lot space left on the right. It should look similar to the left side as in picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150089/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-prabu).